# Nested query DSL in casbah?

Tags: mongodb, casbah

How can I do a nested and/or query in casbah?

For example:

```
val q =  $and( "a"->"b", $or("e"->"f", "e"->"g"), $or("c"->"d", "c"->"e") )
```

This sample doesn't compile, but that's the idea I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: A 3 year user with 45 questions shouldn't still be signing questions!! I have fixed **all** your questions. You need to read help section of the site, this post on meta is also relevant *(from Jeff Atwood himself)* http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/180280

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation says: "$or operator performs a logical OR operation on an array of two or more expressions ", as it is array you should use Seq to delimit conditions.

```
coll.find(MongoDBObject("a"->"b","$or"->Seq(Map("e"->"f"),Map( "e"->"g")),"$or"->Seq(Map("c"->"d"),Map( "c"->"e"))))
```